Pandas Issue: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_group'
I'm trying to get different groups from a grouped dataframe in pandas, but I'm getting an error.
Here's the code:
import pandas as pd 

table = pd.read_csv("April24_HD_T2_MMStack_Default_edges.csv")
table.drop(table.index[0:3], inplace = True)
table.groupby('TRACK_ID', sort = False)

zero = table.get_group('0')

The console outputs the following error:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_group'
Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Try to replace this line table.groupby('TRACK_ID', sort = False) with table = table.groupby('TRACK_ID', sort = False). The error you're encountering is because you're trying to call get_group on a DataFrame object, but get_group is actually a method of the GroupBy object returned by groupby.

The groupby is not an inplace operation and you need to assign the result to a variable in order to access get_group. So, simply just assign it back to the table:
import pandas as pd 

table = pd.read_csv("April24_HD_T2_MMStack_Default_edges.csv")
table.drop(table.index[0:3], inplace = True)
table = table.groupby('TRACK_ID', sort = False)

zero = table.get_group('0')


Thanks for clarifying that. Are the only functions that are inplace functions ones that specifically accept that flag?

@zachdalton mostly yes, but there are a few exceptions
